# Create a tuple of successive elements of a vector divided by each other

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates

I have a member variable of a class, `offsets`, which is a vector with at least`N+1` elements. I would like to create a member function which will return a tuple with `N` entries with values of successive elements of the vector divided by each other. An example is shown below for a specific instance of this function when `N=3`.

```cpp
std::tuple<3> get_shape()
{
    return std::make_tuple(offsets[N]/offsets[N-1], offsets[N-1]/offsets[N-2], offsets[N-2]/offsets[N-3]);
}
```

Is there a way that this sequence can be generalized to implement the function `std::tuple<N> get_shape()`?

Comment: `std::tuple<3>` should be `std::tuple<int, int, int>` (or subtitute int by more appropriate type).

Comment: Why not `std::array` (with possibly for-loop to initialize it)?

Comment: *"Is there a way that this sequence can be generalized"*. Yes with help of [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that was a typo. I will take a look at `std::make_index_sequence`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this with [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

```
template<size_t N>
struct foo {
    std::array<double, N + 1> offsets;

    auto get_tuple() const {
        auto make_tuple = 
            [this]<typename I, I... idx>(std::index_sequence<idx...>) {
                return std::make_tuple((offsets[N - idx] / offsets[N - idx - 1])...);
            };

        return make_tuple(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }
};
```

`std::make_index_sequence<N>` turns into `std::index_sequence<0, 1, 2, ... N - 1>`. This can be applied on a [templated lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) since [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). Where we can access `0, 1, 2, ... N - 1` via the variadic `I... idx`. Now saying `...` inside `std::make_tuple` will unpack all the `idx` numbers into `N` arguments

```
int main() {
    foo<3> f = { 2, -4, 7, 1 };

    auto tuple = f.get_tuple();
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(tuple), std::tuple<double, double, double>>);

    std::apply([](auto&&... rest) {
        ((std::cout << rest << " "), ...);
    }, tuple);
}
```

output:

```
0.142857 -1.75 -2
```

Comment: From OP's example, it would be `offsets[N - indices] / offsets[N - indices - 1]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this answer along with @Jarod42's comment solves the problem perfectly.